# Omit list of vertices in a buffer

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a buffer which contains vertex information which I use for `glDrawArrays`. The triangles in the buffer are spaced around the screen as sprites. I would like somehow to omit drawing some of those items without having to update the entire buffer.

Is there someway I can modify the vertices so that nothing will be drawn when they are encountered?  I don't wish to completely remove it since that involves updating the entire buffer again.

*I'm targetted some devices with only OpenGL ES 2.0 support.*

Comment: @genpfault, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145077/decide-between-generic-and-version-specific-tag-opengl-and-opengl-es

Answer (score 2):

You can use glDrawElements and provide an indices buffer.

Comment: I'd have to reload the buffer for the index list each time then. Granted this is smaller than the vertex data, but still quite large (since each spite requires 6 vertices).

Comment: indices would consume 12 bytes per quad. otherwise, it depends on how many attributes you have per vertex.

Answer (score 1):

`glDrawArrays` has `offset` and `count` parameters. You can use these parameters to draw only the elements within the buffer that are visible. This results in multiple `glDrawArray` calls for a single buffer.

An other alternative is to skip the triangles within the shader using the `discard` command in the fragment shader. In this case you have to provide information about which triangles need to be rendered to the shader (e.g. by uniforms)

Comment: The items which should not be drawn would be kind of scattered, so I might need a lot of draw calls. I was lead to believe that a single call would alway be more efficient (guess I can try that out though).  I've tried discard before and it is quite costly (huge frame rate hit compared to drawing transparent pixel).

Comment: You are right that a single call is more effective than multiple calls. But i dont think there is another way to do this if you don't want to update the buffer every time (or use an index buffer like last GetLastError mentioned). Maybe you can sort the triangles to reduce scattering.